# TomEE cannot find my configured data source

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

I am trying to configure a non JTA data srouce in Tom EE. I created a resource.xml file in my WEB-INF directory and a persistence.xml file in my META-INF directory. The issue seems that Tom EE iss not picking up the data source configured in the resource.xml file. Please assist.

Here is the exception I am getting;

```
EL Severe]: ejb: 2022-02-18 14:27:58.423--ServerSession(726371619)--Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 3.0.2.v202107160933): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [dashboardDS].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [dashboardDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [dashboardDS].
Feb 18, 2022 2:27:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [faces] in context with path [/dashboard] threw exception [jakarta.el.ELException: Error reading [towers] on type [za.co.ezimax.dashboard.Map$$OwbNormalScopeProxy0]] with root cause
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [dashboardDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [dashboardDS].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:833)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:160)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:140)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:807)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:313)
    at za.co.ezimax.dashboard.Database.<init>(Database.java:20)
    at za.co.ezimax.dashboard.Database.<clinit>(Database.java:13)
    at za.co.ezimax.dashboard.Map.<init>(Map.java:15)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.apache.webbeans.inject.InjectableConstructor.doInjection(InjectableConstructor.java:72)
    at org.apache.webbeans.portable.InjectionTargetImpl.newInstance(InjectionTargetImpl.java:201)
    at org.apache.webbeans.portable.InjectionTargetImpl.produce(InjectionTargetImpl.java:184)
    at org.apache.webbeans.portable.AbstractProducer.produce(AbstractProducer.java:134)
    at org.apache.webbeans.component.AbstractOwbBean.create(AbstractOwbBean.java:124)
    at org.apache.webbeans.component.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:66)
    at org.apache.webbeans.context.creational.BeanInstanceBag.create(BeanInstanceBag.java:76)
    at org.apache.webbeans.context.AbstractContext.getInstance(AbstractContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.webbeans.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:125)
    at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.getContextualInstance(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:101)
    at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.RequestScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.getContextualInstance(RequestScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.get(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:71)
    at za.co.ezimax.dashboard.Map$$OwbNormalScopeProxy0.getTowers(za/co/ezimax/dashboard/Map.java)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at jakarta.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:88)
    at jakarta.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:62)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:179)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
    at org.apache.webbeans.el22.WrappedValueExpression.getValue(WrappedValueExpression.java:68)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagValueExpression.getValue(ContextAwareTagValueExpression.java:93)
    at jakarta.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:357)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getValue(UIRepeat.java:303)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.component.UIRepeat.createDataModel(UIRepeat.java:226)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getDataModel(UIRepeat.java:218)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.component.UIRepeat._validateAttributes(UIRepeat.java:892)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:1022)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.component.UIRepeat.encodeChildren(UIRepeat.java:1816)
    at jakarta.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:545)
    at jakarta.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:554)
    at jakarta.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:554)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1897)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:315)
    at jakarta.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:266)
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:870)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1696)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Here is my persitence.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <persistence-unit name="dashboard" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <non-jta-data-source>dashboardDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is my resource.xml file located in WEB-INF directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Resources>
    <Resource id="dashboardDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        jdbcDriver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        jdbcUrl jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dashboard
        password ******
        userName root
        jtaManaged false
    </Resource>
</Resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [JSR 338 Java Persistence API 2.2](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_2-mrel-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf):

> In Java EE environments, the jta-data-source and non-jta-data-source
> elements are used to specify the JNDI name of the JTA and/or non-JTA
> data source to be used by the persistence provider. If neither is
> specified, the deployer must specify a JTA data source at deployment
> or the default JTA data source must be provided by the container, and
> a JTA EntityManagerFactory will be created to correspond to it.

Consequently, you need to specify the datasource via its JNDI name in your persistence.xml.

Resources (in TomEE) are registered by default under `java:openejb/Resource/<id>`.

Therefore, you need to adjust the non-jta-data-source tag to:

```
 <non-jta-data-source>java:openejb/Resource/dashboardDS</non-jta-data-source>
```